# Stepn account: wallet access

Tags: wallet, sol

I signed up to Stepn with a solana wallet and used it in 2022.
Created a new wallet with same seed phrase and accidentally sent funds to “old address”
Now if I type the seed phrase I can access only the new wallet with 0 funds; how can I go to the original wallet?
Thanks